# Getting only first database entry with Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, html, database, fancybox-2

I have a while loop that gets the images from my database. if you click on the image, a box pops up with the corresponding name.

So if the image of an ape is connected to the text "banana" in the database, the popup that occurs when you click on the image of the ape contains the word "banana".

I want to achieve this with Fancybox2. Everything works fine, but the text in the popup only shows the first entry of the database. I've four images in my database and they are all on the screen, but no matter on which image you click, the text in the popup is the text of the first database entry.

I've done my research on the internet and found multiple solutions, like "use classes instead of id's in the jquery file", but none of them are working.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#data">
    <img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>"/>
</a>


<div id="data">
    <p><?php echo $row['name'];?></p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

I know that I use an ID to refer to the content, but I don't know how to make it a class. I hope someone can help me out.

If this is an duplicate question, my apologies. I'm new here and I didn't find any other solutions that could help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @Jeroen: you may not need the `#data` division, neither displaying the content as `inline` but as `html` (directly from the link) so try adding a (HTML5) `data-*` attribute to your `<a>` tags like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#" data-content="<?php echo $row['name'];?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Then, get the content from the `data` attribute and set `type` to `html`, using the `beforeLoad` callback like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "html",
        beforeLoad: function () {
            this.content = $(this.element).data("content");
        }
    });
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Atj29/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much! It now shows the names correctly. Just curious, can I use more then one data-attribute for fancybox? So that I show the name and, for example, the image?

Comment: @KevinKromjong : yes, you could use more than one `data` attribute (for title or adding links to the opened content, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used fancybox in a while, but I am pretty sure that all you need to do, is set the `title` attribute:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#data" title="<?php echo $row['name'];?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $row['image'];?>"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now the title beneath the box shows the right database entry, but the content in the box is still the same

Comment: @KevinKromjong I'm not sure what you mean with the content. Do you need the same text displayed twice? If not, you should get rid of the `div`.

Comment: I want to the name of the project ($row['name']) inside the popup box. The title puts it beneath the popup box, but I want the name of the project inside the box.

Comment: @KevinKromjong Then you should either look at the options of fancybox to see how you can do that or add an invisible list of all your titles with individual ID's (or data attributes, etc.) so that you can access them individually.